# How to read IE and Chrome Cache content programmatically (C#)?

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, google-chrome

I tried reading file at

> 'C:\Users..\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User
>   Data\Default\Cache\f_00ae8a'

in bytes[] and then tried to convert to different Encoding formats but output is unreadable definitely because may be all cache files(js,img,css etc..) are together zipped into part files but i have no clue how to begin with. Any idea ?

Comment: http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/network-stack/disk-cache

Comment: Accessing the disk cache seems an unusual goal. Even when documented (as Chrome's appears to be) the disk cache format may change. Note that @AlexK's link includes the statement "A new version of the cache is under development." Maybe if we knew *why* you wanted to access the disk cache programatically, a better solution could be identified.

Comment: @Danial I want make cache utility tool which can display info about cache items and perform activities like disk usage and cache clearance.

Comment: @AlexK. anything in c#.