# Chrome cache files reader

Tags: c#, google-chrome

I'm interested in viewing the data stored within my chrome cache files at `C:\Users\%user%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cache`
In the same way as CacheView: [How can I read Chrome Cache files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6133490/how-can-i-read-chrome-cache-files)

I've looked at databases **History** and  **Cookies** . Using the following SQLite commands:
**History: Urls**

```
select id,url,title,visit_count,typed_count,time(last_visit_time / 1000000 + (strftime('%s', '1601-01-01')), 'unixepoch') AS Date,hidden from urls
```

**History: Downloads**

```
SELECT downloads.id, downloads_url_chains.url, downloads.received_bytes, downloads.total_bytes,
                                downloads.state, downloads.target_path, time(downloads.start_time / 1000000 + (strftime('%s', '1601-01-01')), 'unixepoch') AS Date, time(downloads.end_time / 1000000 + (strftime('%s', '1601-01-01')), 'unixepoch') AS Date,
                                downloads.opened, downloads.danger_type, downloads.interrupt_reason, downloads.etag,
                                time(downloads.last_modified / 1000000 + (strftime('%s', '1601-01-01')), 'unixepoch') AS Date, downloads_url_chains.chain_index
                            FROM downloads, downloads_url_chains WHERE downloads_url_chains.id = downloads.id
```

**History: Downloads_Url_Cache**

```
SELECT downloads_url_chains.id, downloads_url_chains.url, downloads_url_chains.chain_index FROM downloads_url_chains
```

**Cookies**

```
SELECT host_key,name,encrypted_value,value FROM cookies WHERE value = ''
```

Of which do not carry the underlying metadata of filetypes, sizes or url origin for generally cached data (pngs, mp4s, etc).

**Application purpose**
The resulting application is expected to attain current files count from the cache. Self-updating of course, as a background thread.

I'm therefore over 8hours into this subject, including an initial header-handling class for the first 10characters via binaryReader and UTF-8 decoding. Big mistake. Research branched towards HttpHeader handling, with some Regex.

**Question**: How does a developer access cached files(ie png's) via c-sharp?

Researching further without a developers input, leads me down the HEX memory pointers route. Throwing in some Regex while streaming the file using StreamReader. It has to be easier than that?

More References: 
[Chrome_Disk_Cache_Format](https://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/Chrome_Disk_Cache_Format#Examples) and [How to read IE and Chrome Cache content programmatically (C#)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22807683/how-to-read-ie-and-chrome-cache-content-programmatically-c)

**Update**: Some psuedo

Fails due encoding and padding.

```
GetEncoding(); // Returns ASCII
// freezes System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buf);
// symbol no System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buf);
// encoding no string finalLines = Convert.ToBase64String(thisData, Base64FormattingOptions.InsertLineBreaks);
// symbol no string datas = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(thisData);
string cur = "";
this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate ()
     {
       richTextBox1.Text = Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes(path));
       cur = richTextBox1.Text;
       richTextBox1.Enabled = true;
     });
 // INVAL MAGIC   byte[] decompressed = Decompress(thisData); // it's not gzip compressed as a file
// string[] data = File.ReadAllLines(path); 
Regex encRex = new Regex("^([^;]+);(?:\\s*([^=]+)=((?<q>\"?)[^\"]*\\k<q>);?)*$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: Did you ever succeed in this?  If so, can you update the topic?

Comment: No I didn't, I found that CACHE file structure isn't common and Uni threw me into deep learning, so abandoned this project. An answer would still be appreciated by me.